# How can I read a property of an attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

How do I get the value (`"query"`) of the `Name` property of the `SupplyParameterFromQuery` attribute applied to `Search.Query`?

```
public class Search
{
    [Parameter]
    [SupplyParameterFromQuery(Name = "query")]
    public string? Query { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: No, because "Name" is just an arbitrary property on that particual attribute. Not all attributes have a Name property, but all members have a name.

Comment: What you are actually trying to get there is the value of the `Name` property of an instance of the `SupplyParameterFromQueryAttribute` class, so it's nothing at all like using `nameof`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I'm aware it's a very different thing. I showed it that was as it was easy to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @gunr2171 Yes, I figure if there's a way to do this, it will require the attribute name and the attribute property name. Hence the `SupplyParameterFromQuery.Name` in my example.

Comment: `nameof` is a compile time operator. We're guaranteed that the name of members doesn't change after compile time and so it's safe. There's no such guarantee that an arbitrary property of an arbitrary attribute is even deterministic, let alone fixed at compile time, so you need runtime machinery anyway and at that point, you're already able to write the reflection based code.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes, you're right on all of that. It would've been useful but to your point, it would not have been safe. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.customattributeextensions.getcustomattribute?view=net-7.0#system-reflection-customattributeextensions-getcustomattribute-1(system-reflection-memberinfo)),

```
using System.Reflection;
```

```
var queryProperty = typeof(Search).GetProperty("Query");
queryProperty.GetCustomAttribute<SupplyParameterFromQueryAttribute>().Name
```